# Como generar una tabla con rowspan y colspan en php

Tags: php, html

Mi pregunta es como agregar los atributos colspan y rowspan html a php ya que estoy haciendo una tabla html en php porque necesito descargarla como un archivo.doc pero me genera error aquí:

```
 <?php
header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Conten-Disposition:attachment;Filename=documento.doc");
echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"content-Type\"content=\text\html;charset=utf-8\">";
echo"<body>";
echo "<br><br>Mi primer documento</br></br>";
echo "Aqu&iacute";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>imagen del sena</td>";
echo "<th><h2>FORMATO PARA PROTOCOLO DE DETERMINACION DE MOLIENDA F0205043</h2></th>";
echo "<th><h3>LABORATORIO DE ENSAYOS PARA EL MOBILIARIO </h3></th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<h3>Codigo de la Solicitud del servicio</h3>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h2>1.Informacion de la muestra</h2></th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Fecha y Hora de Ejecucion del Ensayo</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Tiempo dedicado a la Ejecucion del ensayo</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Nombre de la Muestra</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Tipo de Recubrimiento</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Proporcion de Dilucion</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Proporcion de catalizador o Endurecedor</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
echo "</tr>";  
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h2>2.Planificacion del Ensayo</h2></th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Norma o Procedimiento</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Equipos Elementos e insumos utilizados</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>codigo</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Equipos,elementos e insumos utilizados</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Codigo</h3><td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td<h3>rowspan='4'>NTC 557 L0205007</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Calibrador tipo hegman de dos pistas</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Brocha</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Reloj</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Thinner</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Espatula Mecanica</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Estopa</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Lampara</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Beaker</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h2>RESULTADO DEL ENSAYO</h2></th>";
echo "<td><h3>Ensayo 1.</h3></td>";
echo "<td<h3>colspan='2'>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td<h3>rowspan='3'>Resultado promedio</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>Ensayo 2.</h3></td>";
echo "<td<h3>colspan='3'>Incertidumbre de la Aplicacion:No Aplica</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h3>4.VERIFICACION DE LOS RESULTADOS</h3></th>";
echo "<td><h3>Existen Errores</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Si</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>No</h3></td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "<td><h3>Describa los Errores encontrados</h3></td>";
echo "<td<h3>colspan='4'></h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h2>5.OBSERVACIONES</h2></th>";
echo "<td<h2>colspan='5'>combine celdas horizontales</h2></td>";
echo "<td<h2>rowspan='3  '>combine celdas verticales</h2></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

POSSDATA:

Tuve que cambiar las comillas dobles por simples pero igualmente no toma los cambios que se supone he generado con colspan y rowspan.Podria alguien Ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.SO] te sugiero que realices el [tour] y también leas [ask], para que mejores tu pregunta, como tal tu pregunta es de baja calidad, también considera agregar un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: El error esta en la línea 23.

Comment: Puedes obtener el mismo resultado (o incluso mejor) sin usar tantos `echo`.

Comment: Gracias pero continuo con el mismo problema sobre combinar celdas y filas en php con html; Ese es uno de los problemas; por ahi vi que concatenando se solucionaba pero aun no me funciona y no se por que :(

Comment: echo "<td><h3>Describa los Errores encontrados:</h3></td>";
echo "<td colspan=\"3\"><h3>&nbsp</h3></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th colspan=\"4\"><h2>5.OBSERVACIONES</h2></th>";  
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>" ;
echo "<td<h2>colspan=\"5\">&nbsp</h2></td>";
echo "<td<h2>rowspan=\"5\">&nbsp</h2></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</html>";
?>

Comment: Gracias Mariano por corregir la publicacion pero por que mejor no me ayudan a solucionar la duda que tengo. jajajaja

Comment: Por favor puedes editar la pregunta colocando la tabla tal y como la tienes actualmente e indicando el error que te da o lo que no funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Tú puedes mezclar código PHP/HTML en un archivo PHP sin problemas.

Ejemplo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ejemplo de PHP con HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Encabezado 1</h1>
    <p>Este es un documento HTML creado en PHP</p>
    <?php
         //Aquí bloque de código PHP
    ?>
  </body>
     <table>
           <thead><tr><th>Encabezado1</th><th>Encabezado2</th></thead></tr>
                  <tr><td>Celda1</td><td>Celda2</td></tr>
     </table>
    <?php
         //Aquí otro bloque de código PHP
    ?>

</html>
```

Si por algún motivo tienes que construir toda una parte de HTML dentro de PHP, también puedes hacerlo.

Yo en esos casos creo una variable y voy concatenando los valores.

Ejemplo:

```
  $html="<table>";                
    $html.="<thead><tr><th>ENCABEZADO 1</th><th>ENCABEZADO 2</th></tr></thead>";
    $html.="<tbody>";

/*
    * Supongamos que estamos leyendo un conjunto de resultados
    * obtenidos de la base de datos
*/  

    while($data = mi_fetchassoc($stmt))
    { 
/*
    * Dentro del bucle, concatenamos cada valor en filas y celdas de la tabla
    * usando las etiquetas <tr> y <td>
    * Habrá un <td> por cada columna que querramos presentar en la tabla
    * Sustituye $data["...."] en cada td por los nombres de columna de tu tabla
*/  
        $html.="<tr>";
        $html.="<td>".$data["padre"]."</td>";
        $html.="<td>".$data["id_padre"]."</td>";
        $html.="</tr>";
    }

/*
    * Fuera del bucle, completamos nuestra variable $html 
    * Luego la imprimimos
*/  

    $html.="</tbody></table>";
    echo $html;
```